# How are ships stacked ontop of other ships?

Tags: civil-engineering, transportation, ships

As shown at this skeptics SE [post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23913/is-this-a-ship-shipping-ship-shipping-shipping-ships), there are ships that carry other ships as cargo, etc...

[image]

My question: how are the ships stacked onto the flat bed ship? Is there some kind of specialized crane that is able to lift the smaller ships (seems like an intense crane to me!... but I don't know much about cranes)? Or are there other ways stacking ships like this?

Comment: I believe the ships are junks, and only the shells remain, to be transported to the destination for recycling. The port gantry cranes shall be able to handle the task.

Comment: Some ships are designed to carry damaged ships, such as when the [USS Cole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Cole_bombing) was damaged in 2000 by a bombing attack & it was carried to the USA by the [MV Blue Marlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MV_Blue_Marlin), which is semi submersible.

Answer (score 3):

These ships can be loaded/unloaded:

- from a dock

[image]

**Figure : Loading/unloading from a dock (source  [Youtube](https://youtu.be/FvGGtrwlR40?t=70))**

- but they also have they have the ability to submerge in order for their cargo to be loaded/dropped off

[image]

**Figure: Loading Unloading from subversion (source [Youtube](https://youtu.be/FvGGtrwlR40?t=19))**

After a  small search you can see that using the submersible ability those ships where loaded onto the Blue Marlin.

[image]

**Figure :  loading of stacked ships.  [Amazing Ships Youtube](https://youtu.be/KvWvvSx5TEM?t=84)**

Answer (score 2):

Answer: Gantry cranes with submersible dry dock.  It has to be a crane because we have to accurately place one hull on another.

Vessel is Blue Marlin.  Load has been described as 22 barges.  There are barges there to allow hulls to be transported, but mainly inland ship hulls with super structures on top of hulls.

Destination was [Veka shipyard Lemmer](https://www.vekagroup.com/locations/dock-lemmer/), which produce [inland vessels](https://www.vekagroup.com/shipbuilding/inland/).  Largest of these have a tonnage of 6,228 tons.  Let's say 5,000 tons (this is a way over estimate, but good enough to answer question).

[image]

Super-structures (that it is) can be clearly seen on top.

[Sea trials](https://www.vekagroup.com/news/sea-trial/special-simultaneous-sea-trial-mvs-vera-pax-mvs-cortina/) of one or a similar hull.

[image]

To lift 5,000 tons onto a barge, we need gantry cranes with water access.

[30,000 ton gantry crane](https://www.sembmarine.com/scm2016/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Dolphin_Feb20_FA_HR_Single_No-crop.pdf#page=5) with submersible water quay in Singapore by Sembcorp Marine.  The legs are on wheels so the gantry cranes can come closer to each other to lift loads ([Second image](https://www.sembmarine.com/2021/06/29/sembcorp-marine-partners-sp-group-to-integrate-green-energy-tech-at-tuas-boulevard-yard)).

[image]

[image]

[YouTube Video: The 15,000 tons record transport project on Cometto SPMT Self-Propelled Modular Transporter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08I5e43JwJI&t=77s) of cranes ariving in Singapore.